# Problem compilate with gcc & gdb on Vs code with windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, gdb

I’m starting with VScode and I can’t compile my programe corectement in C.
I’ve done a lot of research and I can’t find a solution. Can anyone help me?

C_CPP_Properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\MinGW\\include",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include"

            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Lancer",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Activer l'impression en mode Pretty pour gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Settings.json

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "time.h": "c"
    }
}
```

Task.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe générer le fichier actif",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe "
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "isDefault": true,
                "kind": "build"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()  {
    int i = 1;
    
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Error

```
PS C:\Dev\.git\Code> The program 'C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x00000001).
```

I’d really like to make it work,
I tried to manage on my own but I really didn’t find anything.

I hope the code I put in will be enough to maider.
Thx and have a good day :)

Comment: does it work if you compile manually?

Comment: with powershell the compilation work but with VsCode is doesnt work.